# Slurm - How to create a job array with jobs that are not in the same folder

Tags: cluster-computing, slurm

I have a folder structure which is like this:

```
/home/01/01/script.R
/home/01/02/script.R
/home/01/03/script.R
/home/02/01/script.R
/home/02/02/script.R
/home/02/03/script.R
/home/03/01/script.R
/home/03/02/script.R
/home/03/03/script.R
```

I want to send all of these scripts jointly to the Slurm as one job array. However, I am running into problems because they are not in the same folder. What I currently know how to do is how to send these scripts to Slurm as three separate job arrays - one of which is at `/home/01`, second one at `/home/02` and the third one at `/home/03`. I was wondering if there was an easy way to send all nine jobs together as a part of the array, ***WITHOUT*** putting them all in a same folder - the folder structure needs to strictly stay as is here.

This is the script that I am currently using, which doesn't work:

```
#!/bin/bash
# submit_array.sh

#SBATCH --job-name=array_test
#SBATCH --mail-user=user@test.com
#SBATCH --mail-type=end
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --mem=50                      
#SBATCH --time=0-00:01:00               
#SBATCH --qos=standard

declare -a combinations
index=0
for dataset in `seq -w 01 03`
do
    for chain in `seq -w 01 03`
    do
        combinations[$index]="$dataset $chain"
        index=$((index + 1))

    done
done

parameters=(${combinations[${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}]})

dataset=${parameters[0]}
chain=${parameters[1]}

module add R

cd /home/$dataset/$chain
R CMD BATCH script.R
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What problem are you running into? You have not `--array` parameter in the submission script, but other than that, it should work as is?

Comment: I'm sorry, but after adding the --array argument, I am experiencing some weird behavior. Only 3 out of 9 jobs have started and they are the ones located in /home/01/02, /home/01/03 and home/02/02. I need all 9 jobs to start.

Besides, why would I need to add an array argument if that part should be indicated by the chain part of the for loop? The chain index is the same as the indices that would be used in the array argument

Comment: If I understand correctly - and please let me know if I'm wrong - the `chain`  index has not inherent way to parallelize across nodes. Why use an sbatch array script if you do not want to use the `${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}` that `--array` provides? If you want to use more than one node, you should be able to finish the script execution faster in parallel than running serially.

Comment: @pcamach2 You are completely correct, the only reason why I want to use arrays is because the maintainers of the supercomputer where I will be doing the computations persistently insist for me to do so

Answer (score 0):

One method is to use combine the folder combinations as separate IDs in the sbatch array whose associated `${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}` can be parsed through substring parameter expansion in the shell script as follows:

`sbatch -a 101,102,103,201,202,203,301,302,303 ./submit_array.sh`

where the contents of `submit_array.sh` are:

```
#!/bin/bash
# submit_array.sh

#SBATCH --job-name=array_test
#SBATCH --mail-user=user@test.com
#SBATCH --mail-type=end
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --mem=50                      
#SBATCH --time=0-00:01:00               
#SBATCH --qos=standard

# job arrays do not usually support 4 digits,
# so we append "0" for the dataset variable
dataset="0${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID::1}"
# then chain uses the last two digits
chain=${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID:1:3}

module add R

cd /home/${dataset}/${chain}
R CMD BATCH script.R
```